# No database error on BlockInsert VBA AutoCad

Tags: vba, autocad

I'm using AutoCAD 2013 and I want to import block from another file. I wrote the code below:

```
Dim Zero(0 To 2) As Double
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To 2
    Zero(i) = 0
Next i

Dim BlockRef As AcadBlockReference
FileToInsert = "D:\blocks.dwg"
Set BlockRef = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.InsertBlock(Zero, FileToInsert, 1#, 1#, 1#, 0)
```

but I get the following error:

```
Run-time error '-2145386390 (8020006a)'
No database
```

I find it very strange because the same code worked a week ago and I did't touch none of the files since then...
If I open blocks.dwg there are a few blocks in it, just as they should.

If I comment out this part of the code, the same error seems to move to the next

```
Set ... = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace. ...
```

I would very much appreciate your help,
Špela

Comment: Did you just recently switch to AutoCAD 2013?

Comment: No.. I'm new with AutoCAD and 2013 was the only version I ever used..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the drawing already contains the block, you need to call `InsertBlock` with the block name only. Something like this:

```
Dim exist as Boolean
exist = False
For i = 0 To ThisDrawing.Blocks.Count - 1
  If StrComp(ThisDrawing.Blocks.Item(i).Name, "blocks", vbTextCompare) = 0  Then
    exist = True
    Exit For
  End If  
Next i
ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.InsertBlock(point, IIf(exist, "blocks", "D:\blocks.dwg"), 1, 1, 1, 0)
```